# Beanstalkd Queue Server

Tags: php, beanstalkd

when I set up a beanstalkd instance, for running in a production environment, should I use a separate server instance (Digital ocean) just as Queue Server? So it is better to separate this service from the rest of the system running on a droplet?

Comment: There are two approaches you could follow: A dedicated `VM` or a `container` running on a VM. And yes it is better to separate service from rest of the system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pay attention to the memory and expected throughput of the queue.

If you have above 10k ops/ second than you need to put on a large dedicated instance, otherwise it's good to store on the same server.

Anytime in the future when you want to move it, you simply pause the system move the binlog to the new server and resume your service and will work.